# Unit tests for third party rest services

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing

I have written unit tests for a third party rest API.  These tests are what I would call live tests in that they do test the rest api responses and require valid credentials.  This is required because the documentation provided by the third party is not up-to-date so its the only way of knowing what the response will be.  Obviously, I can't use these as the unit tests because they actually connect externally.  Where would be a good place to put these tests or separate them from mocked unit tests?

I have currently had to comment them out when I check them in so that they don't get run by the build process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use `assumeTrue` for these sort of tests and pass a system property to the tests. So the start of one of your tests would be:

```
@Test
public void remoteRestTest()
{
    assumeTrue(System.getProperty("run.rest.tests").equals("true"));
    ...
}
```

This will only allow the test to run if you pass `-Drun.rest.tests=true` to your build.

Comment: Thanks mikea.  I went with your suggestion but changed the true check around as System.getProperty returns null if the value isn't set:  assumeTrue("true".equals(System.getProperty("run.rest.tests")) );

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are **integration tests**. While the scope of a unit test is usually a single class the scope of an integration test is a whole component in its environment and this includes the availability of external resources such as your remove REST service. Yes, you should definitely keep integration test separate from unit tests. How this can be done in your environment depends on your build process. 
For instance, in case you work with Maven there is a [Maven Failsafe Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) that targets integration testing in your build process.